# Button in MainWindow executes method in UserControl1

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, user-controls

I'm very new to programming and I cant seem to figure this out, reposting this with some more info.
What I have is a MainWindow as well as a UserControl added into the MainWindow as a child. When I press a button in the MainWindow, I want it to call a method in the UserControl, this method is going to hide a grid. This is what I have now...

```
//mainwindow
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl2 uc = new UserControl2();
    uc.MyMethod();
}


//usercontrol1
public void MyMethod()
{
    grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

I have no errors showing, but it isn't hiding the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the fact you should probably be using `MVVM`, you are nearly there.

**MainWindow**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:UserControl2 x:Name="MyControl"></local:UserControl2>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Width="100" Grid.Row="1">Click me</Button>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MyControl.Method();
}
```

**UserControl**

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
       <Label> I want to hide</Label> 
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public void Method()
{
    MyGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

---

**Before Click**

[image]

**After Click**

[image]